# What is the proper naming convention for Maven 3 dependency version properties?

Tags: maven, maven-3

My company uses properties to specify the version number for the dependencies in our Maven 3 POMs:

```
<properties>
    <???>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</???>
</properties>

...

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-awesome-dependency</artifactId>
    <version>${???}</version>
</dependency>
```

We haven't defined a naming convention and as a result they are very inconsistent.

Comment: I would use `my.awesome.dependency.version`

Comment: if this is a dependency from module project or parent project than use      `<version>${project.version}</version>`, otherwise `{artifactId.vetsion}`.

Comment: Most of these dependencies are APIs from other services we have developed. We version and release a suite of these services together so `<version>${project.version}</version>` as Mohit Saluja suggests looks promising.